# 1 of 3 UIButtons allowed to be selected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm making an app where I've got three buttons on the screen. One of the buttons must always be selected. When the app loads the first button is set to selected, and preforms its action. When the user presses another button, the current button is deselected and the new one is selected.

I'm a little new to Objective-C. This is what I came up with, but none of what I was expecting works.
I've setup the buttons outlets in the header.

```
    - (IBAction)buttonSelector:(id)sender
    {
        firstButton.selected = YES;
        secondButton.selected = NO;
        thirdButton.selected = NO;

        if (firstButton.selected = YES)
        {
            [firstbutton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"selected.png"]];
            secondButton.selected = NO;
            [secondButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"un_selected.png"]];
            thirdButton.selected = YES;
            [thirdButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"un_selected.png"]];
        } else if (secondButton.selected = YES)
        {
            [secondButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"selected.png"]];
            firstButton.selected = NO;
            [firstButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"un_selected.png"]];
            thirdButton.selected = NO;
            [firstButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"un_selected.png"]];
        } else if (thirdButton.selected = YES)
        {
            [thirdButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"selected.png"]];
            firstButton.selected = NO;
            [firstButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"un_selected.png"]];
            secondButton.selected = NO;
            [secondButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"un_selected.png"]];
        } else {
            [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"un_selected.png"]];
        }

    }
```

**Edit 1:**

I tried the UISegmentedControl, but it doesn't appear to be able to be customized enough for what I'm looking for. Ideally the buttons will be more along these lines:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPwoR.jpg

The buttons are going to have a background image that will change

Answer (score 5):

You should use `UISegmentControl` for this. That is the exact feature you are looking for. Here is the [apple documentation on this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html)

[Here is a tutorial from Ray wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6) on how to customize UI elements which includes a `UISegmentControl`.

For eg:-

```
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(35, 200, 250, 50);
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
```

Comment: this is definitely helpful. Am I able to add images to the buttons using this? I forgot to include that in my initial question. In my example I was using color just so I could get the buttons working first, then I'd worry about styling them.

Comment: @frostbyte, Yes, check the tutorial mentioned in the question. There is a sample code which shows how to do that.

Comment: I've made an edit to my question. I tried the UISegmentedControl, but it's not giving me the height I'm looking for, which brings me back to thinking using buttons might be the route I'm going to have to take.

Comment: @frostbyte, You can only change width of the segment bar and not height. You might have to try with custom image background for that to look like the image you attached or rather you might have to try subclassing UISegmentControl to get the desired effect. But since you are more inclined to using UIButton for this, you can go ahead with that. What is the exact issue you are facing with above code?

Comment: I will continue to give the the UISegmentedControl a try, to see if I can get it to work with my button images. My problem with the code up top is that none of the if/else if statements appear to work. They don't alter anything but the button I am pressing. If I click all 3 buttons, in the end all 3 buttons will appear selected instead of just 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this task with for loop, firstly just set image to all of your button then change image of selected image.